# How can I make implement tests in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have many legacy projects using .NET Framework 4.8 or older (I know it's sad) in aspx.cs, I want to implement unit testing and didn't find any resources to do TDD with aspx, are there any materials to guide me there?
Other thing is, can I test aspx.cs files, not just only the .cs?

Tried searching for any docs related to unit testing in .NET ASPX, even with VB, but hadn't find any ways to start.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the full .net framework. Upgrade if you can when you can

Comment: Web Forms doesn't lend itself to testing. Far better off moving off Web Forms as quickly as possible. If you must stay in Web Forms, then moving logic out of your code behind files (.aspx.cs) into well written reusable components is your best bet - essentially isolate yourself from Web Forms as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from adding unit tests to existing code, and that even includes the code behind pages. (since they are a .net class).

As for the markup files?

Hum, UI testing is a VERY different approach, and one that not all that great. However, you could give this a try:

[image]

So, you can I suppose try some UI testing here.

However, for existing code in that system? Sure, you can adopt and create a unit testing project.

So both c# and vb.net unit test projects exist here.

Such as:

[image]

As you can see, they are BOTH for the .net framework and don't require the newer .net core frameworks.

At the end of the day?

The newer MVC web applications are more "orientated" towards unit testing not because of some special feature in .net, but that of forcing developers to "more" often keep code separated from the UI vs the code logic. However, these days, I would give up all unit testing for better JavaScript testing in such pages easy.

However, for the most part, you do NOT test the event handlers that arise from a webform page, but in fact test the actions of the code that such a page is to use + consume in the first place.

This is why I suggested and stated that if the project was not written with unit testing in mind, then unit testing not going to be all that great, and you often THEN have to move some code logic out of existing code behind pages to consumable separate class(s), which of course is rather unit-testing friendly. But, it can be a boatload of work.

So, if you have some code you are testing or working on? Move that code out from the current code behind file - refactor to some classes, and then both the web page and your unit tests can now consume, use (and test) that code, and so can the code behind for that web page.

Last but not least?

Do share your current experience with web development, and how you did your unit testing worked in the past for web development. I am MOST curious if such testing EVER included the markup and UI testing. What what web development system do you have experience with and having used unit testing? Were you EVER testing against anything else but defined classes you created? This I want to know!!!